# Android app java.io.NotSerializableException - identifying exception location in the code

Tags: java, android

we received the following stack trace from our analytics tool for our Android app. The issue is that I'm not sure where in the app the exception occurred. I'd like to find out what the reference to 'a.a$7' or 'a.a$7$1' means. Can someone point me in the right direction where to look in the code?

Thanks!

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.mycompany.myproject.ui.public.a.a$7$1)
android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable (Parcel.java:1394)
android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1341)
android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:644)
android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1313)
android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1034)
android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:669)
android.support.v4.b.v.writeToParcel ()
android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray (Parcel.java:1197)
android.support.v4.b.u.writeToParcel ()
android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable (Parcel.java:1363)
android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1268)
android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:644)
android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1313)
android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1034)
android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:669)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped (ActivityManagerNative.java:3282)
android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run (ActivityThread.java:4415)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6872)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mycompany.myproject.ui.public.a.a$7
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal (ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues (ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy (ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal (ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable (Parcel.java:1389)
android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1341)
android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:644)
android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1313)
android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1034)
android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:669)
android.support.v4.b.v.writeToParcel ()
android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray (Parcel.java:1197)
android.support.v4.b.u.writeToParcel ()
android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable (Parcel.java:1363)
android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1268)
android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:644)
android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1313)
android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1034)
android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:669)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped (ActivityManagerNative.java:3282)
android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run (ActivityThread.java:4415)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6872)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get a serializable, but passing a parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

com.mycompany.myproject.ui.public.a.a class have a static inner class, wich seems to be not Serializable.

Are u using ofuscated libraries?

If you can't make class serializable you can add "transient" to the variable.